# Is it possible to force a window to match the size of the widget?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, window

**TLDR:**

I switch between tabs of my program by calling .hide() on the initial widget and calling .show() on the widget to be switched to, but doing this makes it so only the initial widget, and none of the other ones, fit properly within my window.
Is there any way at all to ensure that the window always conforms to however much space the currently shown widget needs?

To be clear, I actually call show()/hide() on QFrames that contain the widgets I'm switching between. The only thing outside a frame is a back button.

**Details:**

Pushing a button in my widget causes .hide() to be called on that widget and .show() to be called on a child widget; this is my program's mechanism for switching between windows/tabs essentially (the main view has multiple buttons each corresponding to a new window, and each window has a back button to get back to the main view)

Upon initially being shown, my window looks fine: all elements in the main view are shown well and fit the window perfectly. But the problem arises when I switch to a different widget (again, I do this by calling .hide() on the current widget and calling .show() on the widget to be switched to). The window remains the same size, even though the widget being switched to is often bigger or smaller than the main view.

Technically, it's QFrames that I'm calling show()/hide() on. The only thing inside each QFrame is a corresponding widget. This way I can have a back button that is independent of which widget I'm on, so not every widget I add needs to make it's own back button.

Layouts don't seem to help here, I guess because they're more meant for managing the sub-widgets of a parent widget as opposed to managing top-level widgets within a window. If I could just resize the window somehow then I could take the dimensions of the current widget and resize the window to be exactly that, but I don't know if a function resizing your window exists.

Comment: "I switch between tabs of my program by calling .hide() on the initial widget and calling .show() on the widget to be switched to" - Sounds to me like a `QStackedWidget` would be the more obvious/natural thing to use.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you for the response. I've looked into that but I don't think it'd allow me to have a Back button, which is mandatory in my situation. Also, my description of how this works was a bit off, I've updated my post (I actually put the widgets inside a QFrame and hide/show the QFrames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a mechanism where window size would automatically adapt to its contents in Qt. You could use `QStackedWidget` and its [´QStackWidget::currentChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentChanged) signal, so you can resize the windows according to which widget you are showing.

You say you require "back" functionality. This too should be trivial to implement using the above mentioned signal and keeping a navigation stack yourself.

Note: this kind of window resizing on its own is usually not something an user would want to happen on a PC, where they might have arranged windows the way they like manually.

Note 2: You could implement similar functionality using the Qt event filter mechanism, and reacting to hide and show events in the filter, and resizing the window accordingly, but this is a... very hacky approach.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, and thank you very much for the help! I didn't know about QStackedWidget, indeed I should switch to that. 
One confusion though: you say I can resize the windows according to which widget I'm showing. It sounds like I should do that manually. I do believe it's possible to get the dimensions of a widget using `size()`, but how would I set the size of the window (which is handled by the OS)?

Comment: Your topmost widget(s), the one without any parent, is also a window. Resize that widget, and window will be resize (and, assuming you are using layouts as you should, all child widgets will be resized by layouts too). Also, you might want to check out *QWidget::sizeHint()* if you want to know what size the widget wants to be (*size()* gives the current size).